How do I disable/swapout light locker on Devuan XFCE
Got a ~10 year old laptop that sometimes has problems with monitor coming back from sleep requiring battery to be pulled to fix. Forums mentioned Lightdm and lightlocker possibly being issues.
I swapped Lightdm to LXDM fine, but it looks like light locker is still there.
I'm trying to figure out where light locker fits in the proccess, but I can't even recall where the script LXDM kicks off my desktop session resides, so I'm asking you guys. Thnaks

It is not a problem of script, then you have to exlpain clarify whether "light locker" is running or not. The script is placed on https://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?t=41964. If you want to disable you said "light locker", do apt remove package-name to delete, or systemctl disable service-name to disable.

By script, I mean commands that start XFCE
IE
LXDM->I log in -> ????->XFCE and Light locker starts

I would suspect something's up with the system clock, such that lightlocker thinks you've been idle for a very long time, and drops into screen-locker mode. It's not unusual for the clock to seem a bit weird while it catches up on the time that the system has been asleep. I would simply hit ctrl-alt-F1 and log in on the VT, and from there use pkill lightlocker.

and then I would uninstall it.

Problem is when it gets into that state, it doesn't seem to wake up enough for ctrl alt f1 to do anything
